# How to compile by MCC when the source has levels of folders?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, mcc

My Matlab source code (.m files) are stored in a hierarchical structure, which has a set of subfolders. I tried to compile them by the following commands in a CentOS server:

```
mcc -v -m a.m a_call_b.m -I ./Funs/*.m
```

But I have a lot of subfolders that I cannot list all of them in the command line. Is there any other way to compile the source files in a hierarchical structure?

Comment: If `mcc` is unable to extract the dependency, you'll have to list them in the command line. When you say you "cannot list all of them", than this probably means "dont want to list all of them"? You don't have to do this manually however...

Comment: @sebastian Could you please show how to list the dependencies in an automated way? Thanks!

Comment: You could check `depfun` for this, though I was thinking that mcc would do this as well.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed this might do as well:

```
mcc -v -m a.m a_call_b.m -I ./Funs/*.m -a ./Funs
```

From the docs on the `-a` option:

*If only a folder name is included with the -a option, the entire contents of that folder are added recursively to the CTF archive*

So you'd only have to specify top-level directories of your application, which presumably are not too many to list.

See:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/compiler/mcc.html

Comment: Problem with this is that you end up including a bunch of files you may not need